# java.io.NotSerializableException - ContactList program

Tags: java

Hey I'm trying so hard to get my write and read methods work, but I don't know what is wrong

Besides that this methods don't work properly, I have to proof in my TestDiskSaving class that the serialization worked. That's why I set it equal to null.
Any ideas?

```
public class TestDiskSaving {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ContactList myList = new ContactList();
        myList.addContact();
        myList.addContact();
        myList.printAll();
        myList.find();

        myList.write();
        myList = null;
        System.out.println(myList);
        myList.read();
        System.out.println(myList);



    }
}
```

```
public class ContactList {
    private ArrayList<Contact> currentContacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    /**
     * Adds a contact to the list at the next unoccupied index
     * 
     * @author Nick
     */
    public void addContact() {
        currentContacts.add(newContact());
    }

    /**
     * returns the size of the contact list
     * 
     * @author Nick
     */
    public int getSize() {
        return currentContacts.size();
    }

    /**
     * take user input and return a new contact
     */
    private Contact newContact() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the person's first name.");
        String newFirstName = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the person's last name.");
        String newLastName = scan.nextLine();

        if (!newLastName.trim().equals(null) && !newLastName.trim().equals("")) {
            Contact theContact = new Contact(newLastName);
            theContact.setFirstName(newFirstName);

            System.out.println("Please enter the person's address.");
            theContact.setStreetAddress(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Please enter the person's email address.");
            theContact.setEmailAddress(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Please enter the person's phone number.");
            theContact.setPhoneNumber(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Please enter any other additional information about the person.");
            theContact.setNotes(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.println(newFirstName + " " + newLastName + " got stored into the contact list");
            return theContact;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You did not enter the person's last name." + "\n"
                    + "The person did not get stored into the contact list.");
            return null;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Prints all contacts stored in the list, alphabetically by last name, then
     * first name. (not case sensitive)
     * 
     * @author Nick
     */
    public void printAll() {
        ArrayList<Contact> printList = currentContacts;
        Collections.sort(printList);
        for (int i = 0; i < printList.size(); i++) {
            printList.get(i).printInfo();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Find contact(s) in contact list by last name
     * 
     * @author Zhixiang
     */
    public void find() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lastName;
        System.out.println("Please enter a last name for search:");
        lastName = scan.nextLine();
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < currentContacts.size(); i++) {
            if (currentContacts.get(i).getLastName().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName)) {
                currentContacts.get(i).printInfo();
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("Sorry. Contact with last name: " + lastName + " not found.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Saves the current list of contacts onto the disk
     * 
     * @author Arman
     */
    public void write() {
        FileOutputStream outFile;
        ObjectOutputStream outObject;
        try {
            outFile = new FileOutputStream("data");
            outObject = new ObjectOutputStream(outFile);
            outObject.writeObject(currentContacts);
            outObject.writeObject(currentContacts);
            outFile.close();
            outObject.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error writing objects to the file: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads any saved data from the disk into memory, and stores it in the
     * currentContacts
     * 
     * @author Arman
     */
    public void read() {
        FileInputStream inFile;
        ObjectInputStream inObject;
        try {
            inFile = new FileInputStream("data");
            inObject = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);
            currentContacts = (ArrayList<Contact>) inObject.readObject();
            currentContacts = (ArrayList<Contact>) inObject.readObject();
            inFile.close();
            inObject.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error reading from the file: " + ioe.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            System.out.println(cnfe);
        }
    }

}
```

```
public class Contact implements Comparable <Contact> {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String streetAddress;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String notes;

    /**
     * Set the last name for contact
     * 
     * @author Arman
     */
    public Contact(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    /**
     * Return last name of the contact
     * @author Zhixiang
     */
    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the last name of the contact
     * @author Nick
     */
    public void setLastName(String newLastName){
        this.lastName = newLastName;
    }
    /**
     * Prints out all data on the contact, formatted for user viewing.
     * @author Zhixiang
     */
    public void printInfo(){
        System.out.println("Name:    "+ getFirstName() + " " + getLastName());
        System.out.println("Phone:   "+ getPhoneNumber());
        System.out.println("Address: "+ getStreetAddress());
        System.out.println("Email:   "+ getEmailAddress());
        System.out.println("Notes:   "+ getNotes());
        System.out.println();
    }


    /**
     * Returns the contact's first name
     * 
     * @author Nick
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Assigns the contact's first name
     * 
     * @author Nick
     */
    public void setFirstName(String newFirstName) {
        firstName = newFirstName;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the contact's street address
     * 
     * @author Nick
     */
    public String getStreetAddress() {
        return streetAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Assigns the contact's street address
     * 
     * @author Nick
     */
    public void setStreetAddress(String newStreetAddress) {
        streetAddress = newStreetAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the contact's email address
     * 
     * @author Nick
     */
    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Assigns the contact's email address
     * 
     * @author Nick
     */
    public void setEmailAddress(String newEmailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = newEmailAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the contact's phone number
     * 
     * @author Nick
     */
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Assigns the contact's phone number
     * 
     * @author Nick
     */
    public void setPhoneNumber(String newPhoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = newPhoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the contact's notes
     * 
     * @author Nick
     */
    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    /**
     * Assigns the contact's notes
     * 
     * @author Nick
     */
    public void setNotes(String newNotes) {
        this.notes = newNotes;
    }

    /**
     * Return formatted entire contact information
     * @author Arman
     */
    public String toString(){
        return firstName + " " +  lastName + " " + streetAddress + " " + emailAddress + " " + phoneNumber + " " + notes ;
    }

    /**
     * Allow making comparison between contacts for sorting
     * Compares this contact to the contact you specify.  Compares by last name then first name alphabetically.
     * Returns -1 if this contact comes before the other, returns 0 if they are exactly the same name, returns 1 if this comes after the other one.
     * @author Nick
     */
    public int compareTo(Contact otherContact){
        if (this.lastName.toLowerCase().compareTo(otherContact.lastName.toLowerCase()) <= -1) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (this.lastName.toLowerCase().compareTo(otherContact.lastName.toLowerCase()) >= 1){
            return 1;
        }
        else if (this.firstName.toLowerCase().compareTo(otherContact.firstName.toLowerCase()) <= -1){
            return -1;
        }
        else if (this.firstName.toLowerCase().compareTo(otherContact.firstName.toLowerCase()) >= 1){
            return 1;
        }
        else return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: I imported for class ContactList the following:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Contact` class does not implement `Serializable`.

Comment: how do I implement to interfaces at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your `Contact` and `ContactList` classes implement [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

```
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact>, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}

public class ContactList {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `Contact` and `ContactList` classes `Serializable`

This is covered in this tutorial:

> http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45

It is covered best by Effective Java (Page 289 onwards) if you can get access to a copy of it, it is well worth a read.

To summarise:

- You need to implement [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

  - You can implement 2 interfaces like this:
    `class C implements A,B {}`
- You need to add a serialVersionUID, this can be skipped, but it is not a good idea.
- All fields of Contact and ContactList need to be Serializable